# node.js creating custom module with function to return a value

Tags: node.js, express, module

I've never had to do this before.  I've created `myModule.GetRecord()` and I can see the `recordset` successfully has the expected record.
However, `ret` in `router.get()` is `undefined`.

I believe because I need to catch the returned value in a callback.

I don't know how to define this module/function for a callback (if that is what I am appropriately looking to do) or how to call this function for a callback.

I've tried a few different things i.e. the typical `GetRecord(ret, function () { ... });`  But didn't see anything that appeared to work.  And I read a bunch on the line but didn't find what I believe I'm looking for.

I really don't care to much about how I get there, but **all I'm really trying to do is have `mm.GetRecord()`'s returned value in some usable form in the `router.get()`**

> --- myModulefile.js ---

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {

    GetRecord: function (id) {
        var sql = require('mssql');

        sql.connect({ user: 'sa', ... database: 'name' }, function (err) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); return null; }
            var cmd = new sql.Request();
            cmd.query('select * from Records where id = ' + id, function (err, rs) {
                if (err) { console.log(err); return null; }
                if (rs.recordset.length > 0) {
                    console.log('rs[0]', rs.recordset[0]);
                    return rs.recordset[0];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

> --- myRouter.js ----

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mm = require('../myModule');


router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var ret = mm.GetRecord(id)
    console.log('ret', ret);
    if (ret == null)
        ret = JSON.stringify({ ID: -1, f1: 'unknown' });
    res.send(ret);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I find the answer after having placed the question on here.

GetRecord() has to be defined with a parameter that recieves the callback passed to it.  And the callback paramater's variable `fn` is used in place of `return`

```
GetRecord: function (id, fn) {
    var sql = require('mssql');

    sql.connect({ user: 'sa', ... database: 'name' }, function (err) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); fn(null); }
        var cmd = new sql.Request();
        cmd.query('select * from Records where id = ' + id, function (err, rs) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); fn(null); }
            if (rs.recordset.length > 0) {
                console.log('rs[0]', rs.recordset[0]);
                fn(rs.recordset[0]);
            } else {
                fn(null);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and

```
GetRecord(id, function(ret) {
   console.log('ret', ret);
});
```